# Программно подписать документ ключем ДСТУ 4145-2002

Tags: java, цифровая-подпись, keystore

Есть хранилище ключей (`Key-6.dat`) создан неким украинским АЦСК.

Подскажите что почитать/изучить чтобы разобраться как на Java:

1. Отрыть хранилище и извлечь ключ
2. Подписать документ
3. Проверить документ

Также интересует нужны ли для этого сертификаты.

Читал [это](http://javatalks.ru/topics/38622) и [это](https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=4205). Последние справедливо для России, и в моем случает по аналогии не сработало.

Есть подозрение, что я чего-то в корне не осознал и поэтому не пойму.

Благодарю!

Comment: Константин, вы решили проблему? Поделитесь результатом, плиз, если да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорей всего стандартными средствами - не получится. Я думаю, что необходимо найти сайт производителя и поискать там API, после чего будет ясно как к нему подойти со стороны ява

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов:

### Платная библиотека от ИИТ

Есть сертифицированная библиотека от ИИТ: https://iit.com.ua/

Чтоб пользоваться библиотекой ее надо купить. (Я ею не пользовался, но почти все используют именоо ее). Я так понял что там есть реализации на C и на Java.

### Бесплатная реализация на JS

Также есть open-source реализация на js: https://github.com/dstucrypt/agent

Пользовался ею, она точно работает и налоговая без проблем принимает ее результаты. Проста в использовании. Если не хотите заносить чемоданы в ИИТ и у вас есть возможность поднять node.js, то это лучший вариант. Поддерживает JKS от приват банка и key-6.dat от других АЦСК.

### Частично реализованная библиотека Bouncy Castle

Также есть open-source реализация на java: https://www.bouncycastle.org/.
Но надо потратить кучу времени на то чтоб разобраться как работает Bouncy Castle, как его расширять и как применять. И что самое важное - не все алгоритмы работают сразу.

Если вкратце - нет поддержки старых алгоритмов. Они были отменены с 01.02.2022 - [источник](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0422-17#Text):

- [HmacGost34311 z1.2.804.2.1.1.1.1.1.2](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z1399-12#Text)
- [Gost34311 1.2.804.2.1.1.1.1.2.1](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z1399-12#Text)

Реализация этих алгоритмов в библиотеке есть, но у них указаны другие идентификаторы и параметрами по умолчанию. Из-за несовпадения идентификаторов и параметров, старые key-6.dat и JKS не работают. Соответсвенно это надо допиливать самому. Займет это уйму времени.

#### Источники:

https://dou.ua/forums/topic/30227/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_(hash_function)

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2_%D0%A0_34.11-94